# Timezone related issues in BigQuery (for partitioning and query)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We have a campaign management system. We create and run campaigns on various channels. When user clicks/accesses any of the Adv (as part of campaign), system generates a log. Our system is hosted in GCP. Using ‘Exports’ feature logs are exported to BigQuery

In BigQuery the Log Table is partitioned using ‘timestamp’ field (time when log is generated). We understand that BigQuery stores dates in UTC timezone and so partitions are also based on UTC time

Using this Log Table, We need to generate Reports per day. Reports can be like number of impressions per each day per campaign. And we need to show these reports as per ETC time.

Because the BigQuery table is partitioned by UTC timezone, query for ETC day would potentially need to scan multiple partitions. Had any one addressed this issue or have suggestions to optimise the storage and query so that its takes complete advantage of BigQuery partition feature

We are planning to use GCP Data studio for Reports.

Answer (score 4):

BigQuery should be smart enough to filter for the correct timezones when dealing with partitions.

For example:

```
SELECT MIN(datehour) time_start, MAX(datehour) time_end, ANY_VALUE(title) title
FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018` a
WHERE DATE(datehour) = '2018-01-03'

5.0s elapsed, 4.56 GB processed
```

[image]

For this query we processed the 4.56GB in the 2018-01-03 partition. What if we want to adjust for a day in the US? Let's add this in the `WHERE` clause:

```
 WHERE DATE(datehour, "America/Los_Angeles") = '2018-01-03'

 4.4s elapsed, 9.04 GB processed
```

[image]
Now this query is automatically scanning 2 partitions, as it needs to go across days. For me this is good enough, as BigQuery is able to automatically figure this out.

But what if you wanted to permanently optimize for one timezone? You could create a generated, shifted `DATE` column - and use that one to `PARTITION` for.

Comment: Note that you can cluster by the timestamp as well, which could also help to reduce costs depending on the query.